# dynamicly add new jcombo box and button to hirearchy

Tags: java, swing, panel, jcombobox, dynamic-programming

So i have a button that is suppose to add a (sub) race option to my swing gui to create hybrid characters the code to actually update the class and stats values works in console but the GUI aspect is proving difficult right now my code does dynamically create the new code but layered INSIDE the add button it need to modify the parent panel not itself. Ideas?

```
if (e.getActionCommand().equals("AddRaceBox")){
        JButton cb = (JButton)e.getSource();
        String[] cRace = new String[75];
        JComboBox[] raceBox = new JComboBox[2];
        raceBox[1] = new JComboBox();
        for (int i=0; i<75; i++){
            cRace[i] = nala.getRaceName(i);
            raceBox[1].addItem(cRace[i]);
            }
        cb.add(raceBox[1]);

        ImageIcon deleteRaceIcon = createImageIcon("1359702329_delete_user.png", "add race icon");
        JButton addRaceButton1 = new JButton(deleteRaceIcon);
        addRaceButton1.addActionListener(this);
        addRaceButton1.setActionCommand("AddRaceBox");
        addRaceButton1.setSize(new Dimension(32, 32));          
        cb.add(addRaceButton1);
        cb.revalidate();
        cb.repaint();
        System.out.println("Add Race Clicked");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

1) why you added a new [`JButton`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html#jbutton) and [`JComboBox`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) to the another, derived `JButton` from [`ActionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

```
JButton cb = (JButton)e.getSource();

.
.

cb.add(raceBox[1]);

.

cb.add(addRaceButton1);
cb.revalidate();
cb.repaint();
```

2) `JButton` misses any [`LayoutManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html), then a new `JButton` and `JComboBox` (added to derived `JButton`) has `Dimmension[0, 0]`

3) for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable

Comment: sure I'm don't want to see something from your above comment, I want an SSCCE, this is something, very diametral, so different thing ...

Comment: see thats the problem, i cal to several outside class files, those build the hierercy for the constructors, and each one is pretty lengthy  and even if i were to remove the elements not related to the hierarchy all the linked class files would still make it a huge file.

Comment: *"see thats the problem, i cal to several outside class files"*  An SSCCE should not do that.  That is the point.  We don't want your entire code-base, just a compilable example to play with & look at.

Comment: and the compilable code is going to need those sub classes and their constructors even if everything is in one file and trimed to just the called constructors it's going to be huge, i'm not sure how to make it much smaller